# Hibernate : ScrollableResults to list

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to do fetch the data from database using ScrollableResults. Part of my code is below :

```
List list = null;
ScrollableResults items = null;
String sql = " from " + topBO.getClass().getName(); // topBO is my parent class so i pass the any of my child class name .
StringBuffer sqlQuery = new StringBuffer(sql);
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
items = query.scroll();
int i = 0;
TopBO topBO;
while(items.next())
{               
  topBO= (TopBO) items.get()[i];
  list.add(TopBO2); // got the exception at this line.
  i++;
  topBO= null;
}
items.close();
```

If i run the above code i am getting runtime error like `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add the value in list which is not initialize.

It may helps you :

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

replace with

```
List list = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `topBO= (TopBO) items.get()[i];` is causing the problem.

I would suggest that you use result set transformer of query something like this

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sqlQuery.toString());
list=query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(YourClassName.class)).list();
```

Comment: I know this. but i want to fetch data using ScrollableResults because it is faster then List. so please help me to solve it.

Comment: I think you should create TopBO object and use its setter properties to set the values from [i]. Note over here that [0] will give the whole array of Object and than from that array you should fetch the value; You should do something like this Object o[]=(Object[])items.get(i). topBO.setId(o[0])....

Comment: And also change items.hasNext() in while loop. And use items.next() instead of items.get().

Comment: How can i use the setter properties of TopBO because of it is dynamic class. we are passing any of child class. so how can i set that property?

Comment: Get a child class use its properties and than assign it to super class.

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please explain more about it?

Comment: I guess the TopBO or/and its child classes are basically Beans(POJOs). So they must have getter and setter methods, so use them.